# Atmega32u4 USB support

Tags: arduino, atmega

I have made a breakout board for a 32u4. I have boot loaded to it using a uno as ISP and a modified Leonardo boards.txt file (I am using a 8MHz ceramic oscillator).
The boot loading works and I can upload sketchs to it using the ISP.

If I try to upload to the chip through a micro USB, I have to reset the chip manually and then I get the following output.

```
     Programmer Type : butterfly
     Description     : Atmel AppNote AVR109 Boot Loader

Connecting to programmer: .avrdude: butterfly_recv(): programmer is not   responding

avrdude: butterfly_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: butterfly_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: butterfly_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: butterfly_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: butterfly_recv(): programmer is not responding
Found programmer: Id = ""; type = 
Software Version = �.p; Hardware Version = .
```

I have tried changing the USB cable. Has anyone else had any similar problems? Also why do I manually have to reset the chip. I would of thought the chip does this with no DTR output from an FTDI.

Thanks for any help